# Twitter API 1.1: Can upload_with_media post the image inline, in the twitter feed?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using upload_with_media, trying to make a tweet having a message, a link, and an image, and I want the image to show up inline, in the feed, not just in the tweet, preferably with a link attached to the image. Like this tweet:

https://twitter.com/zeynep/status/492299393526403073

In that one, the image comes from an og:image tag on the page, but in the tweet the image is not the same as the current tagged image for that url. The html for that image in the tweet details is:

So it's an "Embdedded image permalink", possibly it's the one that was there in the twitter card when that url was first tweeted?

As for my attempts, I used a url of an image, used php file_get_contents to get the image, then saved it, then posted it using /statuses/upload_with_media. The image looks fine in the tweet, but it doesn't appear inline in the feed unless you click "expand".

https://twitter.com/DevDaleg/status/492355931699572736

Then there's this one, which I did manually using Twitter's UI for posting text with a photo. The image in this case DOES appear inline in the feed! That's what I want mine to look like.

https://twitter.com/DevDaleg/status/492375853024555008

To summarize, I don't think it's possible to have a link and an uploaded image attached to the link. Failing that, I'd like an api posted tweet to look like the result of the manually posted tweet, that is, having an image inline in the feed.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. If the image has proportions of 2:1, and the width is at least 440 px, then it will show inline, so 440x220 and 1024x512 both show inline, but 400x200 does not, and neither does 440x170.